# Ansible & Jinja2 - Set other host in jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

There is a master/slave setup.

Goal:

Set `{{ other_host_of_play }}` in a jinja2 template. Example;

The content of `node1` should contain `node2`

Tried `{{ play_hosts[0] }}`, but this sets the first host of the play, instead of the 'other host'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove or exclude an item in an Ansible template list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696130/how-to-remove-or-exclude-an-item-in-an-ansible-template-list)

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you have tried before? Some code examples etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am allowed to do this. But the answer was actually in the post @konstantinSuvorov provided.

```
{{ play_hosts | difference([inventory_hostname]) }}
```

[How to remove or exclude an item in an Ansible template list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696130/how-to-remove-or-exclude-an-item-in-an-ansible-template-list)

Comment: I think the preferred way of handling this is to either vote to close your own question as duplicate or delete it altogether (as it's a duplicate). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254647/ability-to-close-my-own-questions-as-duplicates